# Convert snake_case to lowerCamelCase in Python

Tags: python, regex

Trying to replace _(character) with just its Uppercase variant.
For example:

```
hello_string_processing_in_python to helloStringProcessingInPython
```

Since string is immutable in Python, how can string substitution be done efficiently?

```
ss = 'hello_string_processing_in_python'
for i in re.finditer('_(\w)', ss):
    ????
```

Comment: Do you mean the upper case of next character?

Comment: Why do you want to do this with regular expressions?

Answer (score 7):

You may try this,

```
>>> s = "hello_string_processing_in_python"
>>> re.sub(r'_([a-z])', lambda m: m.group(1).upper(), s)
'helloStringProcessingInPython'
```

Comment: Elegant. Can you compare it's performance with loop-over-string?

Answer (score 2):

No split or regex is needed and it also ensures that the first character is lowercase:

```
lower_camel_case = ss[0].lower() + ss.title()[1:].replace("_", "")
print(lower_camel_case)

helloStringProcessingInPython
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using regular expressions, you could also just loop through the string and build a new one (`new_string`):

```
s = "hello_string_processing_in_python"

new_string = ""
capitalize_next = False
for character in s:
    if capitalize_next:
        new_string += character.upper()
        capitalize_next = False
    elif character == '_':
        capitalize_next = True
    else:
        new_string += character

print new_string
```

will print

```
>>> 
helloStringProcessingInPython
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the help of a callback function with re.sub:

```
import re
def repl(m):
    return m.group(1).upper()

ss = 'hello_string_processing_in_python'
print re.sub(r"_(\w)", repl, ss)
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/7lYQ5w)

Answer (score 0):

As a none regex solution you can split your string with `_` and just capitalize your words and join it :

```
>>> ''.join([i.title() for i in ss.split('_')])
'HelloStringProcessingInPython'
```

But if you are looking for a regex way you can use `re.sub` for replacing sting with regex. if you want to replace `_` with the upper case of its next character you can do  :

```
>>> ss = 'hello_string_processing_in_python'
>>> re.sub(r'_(\w)',lambda x:x.group(1).upper()+x.group(1),ss)
'helloSstringPprocessingIinPpython'
```

Or if you want replace its next character with uppercase, you need to add with `x.group(1)`:

```
>>> re.sub(r'_(\w)',lambda x:x.group(1).upper(),ss)
'helloStringProcessingInPython'
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj Sorry what?

Answer (score 0):

`a = 'hello_string_processing_in_python'`

`b = a.split('_')`

`c = b[0]+''.join([i.capitalize() for i in b[1:]])`

Output- `'helloStringProcessingInPython'`

Comment: you can use `.title()` instead of looping over string, for what you are doing to get c.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another way to do this:

```
def to_camel_case(input_str):
    words = input_str.split('_')
    return words[0] + "".join(x.title() for x in words[1:])
```